# Creating Dynamic SSH tunnel between 3 computers

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, reverse-proxy

So I have the following setup:

Computer A, Server, Computer B

Computers A and B can SSH to the server but not vice versa. The goal is to achieve dynamic SSH tunneling from A to B through the server so that A can browse dynamically using B's computer.

Moreover, both A and B cannot accept SSH connections at all - only send (Not even from themselves). that means that opening a SOCKS5 server to themselves using:

```
ssh -D 8000 localhost
```

Is really not possible.

I've been able to redirect all traffic from A to the server running the following on Computer A:

```
ssh -D 1080 server_ip
```

But now I want to use Reverse Dynamic SSH tunneling and it doesn't seem to work by running the following on Computer B:

```
ssh -R 1080 server_ip
```

Is there any way to do this? Any other solution I found doesn't hold up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ssh -D` it's the SSH *server* who really connects to the desired address (e.g. to the address you type in your browser configured to use SOCKS).

If you want to "browse dynamically using B", then you need to make the SSH server on B create connections on your behalf. But if B cannot accept SSH connections *at all* then there is no way you can reach its SSH server. In the setup you described, there may be no SSH server on B in the first place.

It would be different if B could accept SSH connections (at least from itself); or if it hosted a SOCKS server accepting connections on some TCP port (at least from B itself).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see what you mean. Do you happen to know how I would go about creating a local SOCKS server on B that accepts connections from the server? Implementation-wise I mean. Or is there an easy way to create an SSH server that handles only local requests? Computer B runs Windows.

Comment: @RoyZohar I *guess* one can install SSH server or SOCKS proxy on Windows, then configure it (and/or the firewall) accordingly. I cannot guide you though, I'm a Linux guy.